# How can I divide output with delimiter?

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing

I would like to change:

```
e·ver·y·bo·dy
```

to:

```
e·ver·y·bo·dy
e·ver·y·bo·
e·ver·y·
e·ver·
e·
```

A `for` loop will be greatly preferred.

Comment: so you want to split only the lines which has a dot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This also uses a `for` loop, albeit an awk `for` loop:

```
$ echo "e·ver·y·bo·dy" | awk -F· -v OFS=· '{print;for (i=NF;i>1;i--){$i="";print;NF--} }'
e·ver·y·bo·dy
e·ver·y·bo·
e·ver·y·
e·ver·
e·
```

#### Alternate version from short to long

```
$ echo 'e·ver·y·bo·dy' | awk -F· -v OFS=· '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){for (j=1;j<=i;j++)printf "%s%s",$j,j<NF?OFS:"";print""} }'
e·
e·ver·
e·ver·y·
e·ver·y·bo·
e·ver·y·bo·dy
```

#### Another Variation

```
$ echo 'e·ver·y·bo·dy' | awk -F· -v OFS=· '{s="";for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){s=s OFS $i; printf "%s",substr(s,2); print (i==NF)?"":OFS} }'
e·
e·ver·
e·ver·y·
e·ver·y·bo·
e·ver·y·bo·dy
```

Comment: Where is first line (Hi)? and where are dots at the ends?

Comment: @KasiyA OK.  See updated answer.

Comment: You just printed it inside awk (print Hi). If you prefer this solution then you can print all of them by `print` command. So the answer is not good.

Comment: Hey KasiyA, I believe it will work for me as intended. In fact I preferred John1024's first answer, since I will use a for loop to run the script individually for separate words.

ex.
`echo "hi" | awk -F· -v OFS=· '{for (i=NF;i>0;i--){NF=i;print} }'`

Comment: @user264974 Your question is not clear. If you prefer this solution you can use printf command to print your desired output and as I seen his first solution doesn't print the dots at the end. if you want that solution I wil l post the shortest solution after editing your QUESTION.

Comment: My apologies KasiyA, I do agree it was my fault. Let me remove the "hi" part

John, can you please show me a variant that will make the output small to big?

Comment: You are right KasiyA, his first answer did not print the dots at the end. I overlooked that, however, his second version fixed that. I took out the "Hi" part since I want to do one word at a time: `echo "e·ver·y·bo·dy" | awk -F· -v OFS=· '{print;for (i=NF;i>1;i--){$i="";print;NF--} }'` 

Is my question better? I would like to see your solution too, I would really like to learn different perspectives

Comment: @user264974 I just updated with a "small to big" version.  Let me know if it is what you need.

Comment: Got it, I greatly appreciate your help, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by shorter [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) command as below (**long to small**):

```bsh
$ awk -F'·' '{while (NF){ print $0;NF--;ORS="·\n"}}' OFS='·' file
e·ver·y·bo·dy
e·ver·y·bo·
e·ver·y·
e·ver·
e·
```

And from **small to long** as following:

```bsh
$ awk -F'·' '{i=1; while(i<NF){ print tmp=tmp$((i++))"·"} print $0}' file
e·
e·ver·
e·ver·y·
e·ver·y·bo·
e·ver·y·bo·dy
```

Comment: Got it KasiyA, thank you for your method too, it works great. I like your method a lot too!

Answer (score 1):

If it has to be a `for` loop:

```
IFS=·
for l in $(echo "e·ver·y·bo·dy"); do x="$x$l·"; echo "$x"; done | tac
```

First we have to set the [internal file separator](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html) to `·`. Then the for loop runs trough each peace and prints it, but in the wrong order. That's why `tac` at the end reverses the order.

Gives me the output:

```
e·ver·y·bo·dy·
e·ver·y·bo·
e·ver·y·
e·ver·
e·
```

Comment: Hey chaos, thanks for a second variation. Your script is almost just what I need, however, I am not seeking the last dot on "e·ver·y·bo·dy·"

I think I am going to need the tac or rev commands to reverse the order, so good call on that one

Comment: Hey chaos, thanks for the help, I wish I can give you a vote up for trying to help, but I don't have the rep for it.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `python` solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
input_str = 'e·ver·y·bo·dy'
input_list = input_str.split('·')
print input_str
i = len(input_list)
while i > 1:
    print '·'.join(input_list[:i-1]) + '·'
    i -= 1
```

Here we first `split` the input string using `·` as the delimiter to generate a list and then used list slicing and `join` to get the desired output.